# Alexa API to get all permissions granted for the skills installed

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am new Alexa and want to create a skill which can return all the permissions for other skills. For example a skill for current weather is consuming device location permission and etc.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you can achieve it, because every skill is sandboxed. So it means you cannot access info about other skills.